# How to parse XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Here is the XML I want to parse:

```
"<Result>"
+ "<columnName><![CDATA[Role_Id]]></columnName>"
+ "<Row><col><![CDATA[0]]></col><col><![CDATA[zero]]></col></Row>"
+ "<Row><col><![CDATA[1]]></col><col><![CDATA[one]]></col></Row>"
+ "<Row><col><![CDATA[2]]></col><col><![CDATA[two]]></col></Row>" + "</Result>";
```

and I would like the following output:

```
0,zero
1,one
2,two
```

but when I'm trying to parse it, I get

```
0 1 2
```

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: you can use JAXB. that's very fast way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use JAX-B, it should do the trick pretty easily.

An "hello world" example for JAX-B: http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/

Comment: can go more into detail please? E.g. provide a link.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library such as DOM, JDOM, SAX, etc. There are many tutorials available on the Internet for that.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT comes to mind:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/Result">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Row"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row">
        <xsl:value-of select="col[1]"/>,<xsl:value-of select="col[2]" />
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

Another alternative to XSLT would be SLAX. Syntax is much better on the eyes, and more fun to write:

[libslax](http://code.google.com/p/libslax/)